# Setting up Firewall on RaspberryPi

Tags: raspbian, services, systemd

As default, Raspbian loads `firewalld.service` on boot.

I wish to define firewall's inbound and outbound ports in order to allow services such as `pigpiod`, VNC, SSH and so , to be able to control each other.

When using Ubuntu Mate- it is easy to download from Software center, a firewall software to control its firewall.

While using Raspbian - I don't find a porper way to do it. Googling around led to install `ufw` which is very minimal in capabilities and tiresome to work that way.
Plus- `systemctl enable ufw` did not load it after boot.

I would love to get some help with this,

Guy

Comment: What is the name of the package you installed on Ubuntu Mate?

Comment: Firewall is built into the kernel and interfaced with `iptables`, `ufw` is "uncomplicated firewall" and is a wrapper for iptables. Anything you can do with any firewall config tool you can do through `iptables`, but the syntax/usage is very archaic. What about `ufw` is insufficient for your purposes? there are graphical wrappers for UFW like `gufw`

Comment: @crasic - thanks for you answer. firstly - archaic is mostly what bothers me ( since it all typ2ing, and don't have the flexabililty to define "home" ,"public" and so  ).

Comment: @MarkStosberg - something more like "firewall-config" which can be downloaded via Ubuntu's software center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up ( thanks to @crasic and @Mark ) - installing `sudo apt-get install gufw` install gui for `ufw` which a `systemctl` service,

`sudo apt-get install firewall-config` install gui for `firewalld`.

thanks alot !